# Run a local command on a remote machine

Tags: ssh, python

I have a python script (audit.py) which collects information about a machine and prints the output at the end.

Along the way it asks for user input (using Pythons' raw_input functionality).

Is there a way to run this script on a remote machine, saving the output to a local file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both servers are some sort of *nix install, have ssh keys set up for password-less logins, and the remote server has python.

Copy the script to the remote server:

```
scp audit.py serveraddress:~
```

Run the script on the remote machine, and save the output to a local file:

```
ssh serveraddress "./audit.py" >outputfile
```

If you are running it as a script, send it the input it needs:

```
cat input_for_auditpy | ssh serveraddress "./audit.py" >outputfile
```